# I.E 8 issue With jquery Slide

Tags: jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, slide

Hi You can look [here](http://www.sab.org.tr/) for problem..
It says:

```
SCRIPT5007: 'toLowerCase' Unable to get value of property: the object is empty or undefined..jquery.slider.min.js, line 398..
```

I dont know jquery. How can I fix this problem with IE-8.. I must use IE-8.. I added my MasterPage `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />` tag for IE-8..

Comment: what is the name of your slider jquery!!! is it jQuery Slider²?

Comment: can you paste here!! all images is static or dynamically bind with jquery!!

Comment: yes it is jquery slider.. You can look error from my link.. At slider numbers disappearing for IE-8 and I must use IE-8.. and my ımages are dynamically binding from my contents..

Answer (score 0):

Many JavaScript libraries (especially non-recent ones) do not handle IE9 well because it breaks with IE8 in the handling of a lot of things.

JS code that sniffs for IE will fail quite frequently in IE9, unless such code is rewritten to handle IE9 specifically.

Before the JS code is updated, you should use the "X-UA-Compatible" meta tag to force your web page into IE8 mode.

Comment: I see your page source and I didn't find this meta tag in it.. Please add it at proper place, The solution of your problem is this. try this meta tag at proper place.

Answer (score 0):

I know cause might not be the same, but just for others who might get the same / similar error :

I was getting

```
Unable to get value of the property 'toLowerCase'
```

From IE9, but also

```
TypeError
arguments: Array[2]
0: "toLowerCase"
1: undefined
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
get message: function getter() { [native code] }
get stack: function getter() { [native code] }
set message: function setter() { [native code] }
set stack: function setter() { [native code] }
type: "non_object_property_call"
__proto__: Error
```

From Chrome's developer tools.

It had nothing to do with Jquery bugs (old versions) or any of the other solutions I found on the web when googling.

It was my stupid fault for not keeping track of what I was up to. I was using

```
var targetRow = $(this).closest("tr")[0];
```

And "this" was not what I thought it was (thought it was a link tag, think it was the whole window or document or something else, but certainly was not what I though it was).

My own damn fault.

Just might help out someone else having a JScript Muppet moment :)